# Acess variables in DAML template like in an object

Tags: daml

Okay am new to DAML and have extensive Java programming experience. Now, I have a question. In Java, 'Class A' has 'Class B', and like this, A can use 'state' of 'Class B'. I want to do something like this in DAML too.

If I think template as a class, 'contract id' is an instance of it, and the 'state' of the template (the things we declare in 'with') should be accessible in another template when passed in as a parameter, but I get compilation errors in the code I wrote.

One way to proceed is to send 'party' as a parameter instead of contract ID, and then try to access the party in contract, but I wanted to check if/ what is wrong with this!

Thanks in advance!

First template

```
daml 1.2
module RFP where

template RFP
with
        requestorCEO: Party
    where
        signatory requestorCEO
```

Second template

```
daml 1.2

module InternalComm where

import RFP

template InternalComm 
    with
        -- RFP is sent in as a parameter to this template.
        rfpContractID: ContractId RFP
    where
        -- Here with this, I'm trying to say that the CEO who would be approving 
        -- an RFP is the signatory for internal communications too. It is the
        -- below line that fails with compilation error.
        signatory rfpContractID.requestorCEO
```

This is the actual error message I get for aforementioned problem. Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
No instance for (DA.Internal.Record.HasField
                         "requestorCEO" (ContractId RFP) a0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DAML the RFP template gives you a type `RFP` on which you can project out the fields (just like Java), and a type `ContractId RFP` which is more like a pointer to the contract on the ledger. You can "dereference" the `ContractId` to get the `RFP` using the function `fetch`. However, that function runs in an `Update`, so can't be called from a `signatory`. I suspect you need to change `InternalComm` to take a `RFP` without the `ContractId` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked - just remove ContractId from whole of the template.

```
module InternalComm where

import RFP

template InternalComm 
    with
        -- ContractId to be removed from below line, and compilation error is resolved.
        -- rfpContractID: ContractId RFP
        rfpContractID: RFP
    where
        signatory rfpContractID.requestorCEO
```